# Accessing json response from the server in Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have an Ember CLI app with Rails as backend API. At some point I perform an action (a `model.save()` in this case) and want to get a custom json response from the server to access it from my Ember app. I'm getting the response I want, I'm just not sure how to handle it in Ember, how to gain access to the object and its properties. I know I can use `.then()` and put something between those parentheses, but this will be Ember's response with the saved object, not the json I get as a response from the backend.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're more likely to get a good answer if you provide that isn't working. If it's long, try to trim it down to just what is directly relevant to your question here. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: Interesting question. Don't know about such possibility. Why do you need it, anyway?

Comment: Are you referring to ember data? Ember  and ember data are two different products

Comment: If Ember Data returns a `DS.Model`  in `then()` and that "something" is not model data, you can try sending metadata (`meta`) from Rails and retrieve that back in Ember Data: http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/handling-metadata/